# Eloquent - Random from a existing list

Tags: php, laravel, random, laravel-5, eloquent

I see that I can get a random row in Laravel 5 by:

```
Model::inRandomOrder()->get();
```

But I want to get all from Model and pick a random object from it like below.

```
$models = Model::all();
$model = $models->getRandom();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try $models->random();

Comment: is this even possible?

Comment: Refer to the Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-random, you just need to have a collection and I do believe all() returns an array.

Comment: Maybe you can try $models = Mode::get(), $model = $models->random();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this should work:

```
$models = Model::all();
$model = $models->random();
```

Or even this:

```
$models = Model::get();
$model = $models->random();
```

Answer (score 0):

## two sugestions:

### 1. get your data twice:

```
 $models = Model::all();
 $model = Model::inRandomOrder()->get();
```

### 2. select a random row from the retrieved data:

```
 $models = Model::all();
 $model = $models[rand(0, count($models) - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using array_rand function in php.**
[array_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand)

```
$models = Model::all()->toArray();
$id= array_rand(Model::all()->toArray()); //this will return the id of a random element in the array
$model = Model::findOrFail($id);
```